# Crystal reports font size

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

How do I set the font size of a Crystal Report in C# ASP.NET?

Comment: Do you mean setting the font for the whole report at Design Time using Visual Studio or using Crystal Reports? Or do you want to change the font for the whole report at run time. Or do you want to change one fields font at run time? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the formula button next to size and put your conditional formula there as "if condition then fontsize# else fontsize#"
Example: if {tbl.color}="red" then 10 else 8